# How to find out from the slot which signal has called this slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals, qmetaobject

I mean if I have many different signals which are connected to the same slot. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988562/how-to-determine-which-signal-emited-from-a-slot) question but can't understand [the link](http://web.archive.org/web/20111205031906/http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html) in the answer. Can you give me simple example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can use this method:
[`[protected] int QObject::​senderSignalIndex() const`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qobject.html#senderSignalIndex)

From Qt documentation:

> **Returns the meta-method index of the signal that called the currently executing slot**, which is a member of the class returned by sender(). If called outside of a slot activated by a signal, -1 is returned.
>
> For signals with default parameters, **this function will always return the index with all parameters, regardless of which was used with connect()**. For example, the signal destroyed(QObject *obj = 0) will have two different indexes (with and without the parameter), but this function will always return the index with a parameter. This does not apply when overloading signals with different parameters.
>
> **Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity**. However, getting access to the signal index might be useful when many signals are connected to a single slot.
>
> **Warning: The return value of this function is not valid when the slot is called via a Qt::DirectConnection from a thread different from this object's thread.** Do not use this function in this type of scenario.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 4.8.

Here is a small example that I created for you that demonstrates how it works:

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaMethod>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
        void mySlot() {
            QMetaMethod metaMethod = sender()->metaObject()->method(senderSignalIndex());
            qDebug() << metaMethod.name();
            qDebug() << metaMethod.methodSignature();
            qApp->quit();
        }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    QTimer timer;
    Foo foo;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &foo, &Foo::mySlot);
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    timer.start(1000);
    return coreApplication.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"timeout"
"timeout()"
```

Comment: Thx. And is there way to do this with `QSignalMapper`? Qt docs has only variant with pushbutton, but what i must do if i want to use `QSignalMapper` with `QLineEdit`?

Comment: @9vashrotebal: you can use QSignalMapper with QLineEdit, too, of course, but I would not know how to get a signal name and not just the sender out of that without my solution.